# Issues with custom RP2040 board

Tags: pi-pico, usb-c

I have made a custom RP2040 PCB. When I connected the PCB using USB to PC, it is attaching as mass storage device. But when I am copying a uf2 file for blink and it got unmounted. But nothing is happening.

If I am copying uf2 file for micropython, then the PCB is getting re-mounted automatically after some times and the uf2 file is getting removed. It's like the PCB is vomiting the micropython uf2 file.

Using winbond W25X20CL flash.

Comment: Any schematic? Or just copycating AdaFruit etc?

Comment: I am using the schematics they have given in RP2040 datasheet. The example pcb

Comment: I see. So you started with the datasheet's Section 5.1.1 Recommended PCB Footprint? https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf

Comment: I actually refer to this pdf - https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf
The example PCB in chapter 2

Comment: @tlfong01 any comments on this? Please let me know

Comment: Well, I usually don't start with the PCB, I start with ugly looking proto board. Techniques and Strategies for Building Electronic Circuits
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq968AFgPhg. BTW, the Ch 2's example board tutorial is very good.